# Improving Build Time for Large Angular App

Tags: angular, performance

I have an Angular 2+ application that is fairly large and takes about 10 minutes to fully build.

I’d like to refactor my code base in an attempt to reduce the time taken to build.

I had some ideas but my 3 primary ones were:

- Use a tool like `depcheck` in order to remove unused dependencies
- Update all npm packages to their latest versions
- Possibly optimizing the gruntfile?

Are these some good things to do for a first attempt? What other options should I explore in order to further improve the build time?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can upgrade it to letest version of Angular since letest version of Angular is too fast and even the issues you are facing right now in development will be reduced as well. Aand if you don't want to upgrade it then as @Aarsh suggested, make use of AOT

Answer (score 7):

The below command is very useful to reduce build time:

```
ng build --source-map=false
```

Source map is only needed for debugging, so if you don't want that you can surely use that command.

Another one is

```
 --build-optimizer=false
```

Other than that, use AOT - ahead of time compiler. You can [learn more about AOT here](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler).

From your question, the second option might not have much effect on build time. I don't know about depcheck and optimizing gruntfile.

Comment: AOT is increasing build time. OP is trying to reduce it.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me, just to correct the first command it's --source-map=false, at least the without this - i got unknown command sourcemap

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--prod` flag if you're planning to deploy:

`--prod` enables the following flags:

```
Flag                  --prod
--aot                 true
--environment         prod
--output-hashing      all
--sourcemaps          false
--extract-css         true
--named-chunks        false
--build-optimizer     true with AOT and Angular 5
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

> **Ahead-of-Time (AOT) Compilation:** pre-compiles Angular component templates.
>   
> **Production mode:** deploys the production environment which enables production mode.
>   
> **Bundling:** concatenates your many application and library files into a few bundles.
>   
> **Minification:** removes excess whitespace, comments, and optional tokens.
>   
> **Uglification:** rewrites code to use short, cryptic variable and function names.
>   
> **Dead code elimination:** removes unreferenced modules and much unused code.
>
> The remaining copy deployment steps are the same as before.
>
> You may further reduce bundle sizes by adding the build-optimizer flag.
>
> `ng build --prod --build-optimizer`

https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: I don't see how this is helping with reducing _build time_ as it is enabling build features extending its complexity for the sake of easier loading at runtime of application.